# PHP pthreads with pools and waiting for collecting result

Tags: php, pthreads

I'm using a combination of pools and Promise (wait for the result from the thread) in phreads, but I'm not so good at programming. I'm trying to get the variable $variable accessible in the code where I have written "// I don't know how to access the variable $variable here for the function checkvariable"

But I dont know if this is the correct way of solving my problem, I want to have 10 threads running, and in each thread I need another 10 threads running to give back a result. When the result comes the 1 of the first 10 threads executes a task and stops.

I would be very grateful for your help!

```
<?php

class Pool extends Pool {
    public $data = [];

    public function process() {
        // Run this loop as long as we have
        // jobs in the pool
        while (count($this->work)) {
            $this->collect(function (CheckThis $job) {
                // If a job was marked as done
                // collect its results
                if ($job->isGarbage()) {
                    $this->data[$job->query] = $job->html;
                }

                return $job->isGarbage();
            });
        }

        // All jobs are done
        // we can shutdown the pool
        $this->shutdown();
        return $this->data;
    }
}

class CheckThis extends Collectable {
    public function __construct($variable) {
        $this->variable = $variable;
    }

    public function run() {

        // $this->variable exists here

        $promise = new Promise(function () {

            // I don't know how to access the variable $variable here for the function checkvariable

            return checkvariable($variable);
        });

        $promise->then(function ($results) {

            if ($results) {
                workonresult();
            }
        });         

        $this->setGarbage();
    }
}

class Promise extends Thread {
    public function __construct(Closure $closure) {
        $this->closure = $closure;
        $this->start();
    }

    public function run() {
        $this->synchronized(function () {
            $closure = $this->closure;

            $this->result = $closure();
            $this->notify();
        });
    }

    public function then(callable $callback) {
        return $this->synchronized(function () use ($callback) {
            if (!$this->result) {
                $this->wait();
            }

            $callback($this->result);
        });
    }
}

$pool = new Pool(2, Worker::class);

$pool->submit(new CheckThis($variable1));
$pool->submit(new CheckThis($variable2));

$data = $pool->process();
var_dump($data);
```

?>

I tried this, but it does'nt work ofcourse:

```
    public function run() {

        $variable = $this->variable;

        $promise = new Promise(function ($variable) {
        return checkvariable($variable);
    });
```

Update, this does not work either:

```
public function run() {

    $variable = $this->variable;

    $promise = new Promise(function () use ($variable) {
    return checkvariable($variable);
});
```

Comment: Are you looking for  `use` keyword?

Comment: I mean something like my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Use `use` keyword

```
$variable = $this->variable;

$promise = new Promise(function () use ($variable) {
    return checkvariable($variable)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip that should have worked, but I inserted that code, checked that the $variable had an value before new Promise, but inside new Promise it's still empty.